# Stretching input[type="text"] to fill space

Tags: html, css

I have the following setup:

```
<div style="position: fixed; margin: 0px; background-color: black; height: 100px; width: 100%;">
  <input type="text" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; margin: 30px 30px 15px 30px;" />
</div>
```

The intent is to stretch the  tag to fill the containing `<div>` tag's space (less margins, of course). This works in all latest browsers if I change the `<input>` tag to a `<div>` tag, but as shown here this only works in WebKit browsers (Chrome and Safari). Is there any way to get the desired effect in FF and IE9+ (just IE10 would be sufficient)?

Comment: Please use backticks to format inline code, see my edit.

Comment: I don't think such thing is possible using pure CSS, you will have to use some JavaScript.

Comment: @gzak why can't you just use `width:100%;height:100%;` on the input ?

Comment: try removing (on your CSS file) the browser's defaut CSS settings for the input tag

Answer (score 2):

Try giving width in % to input....
This thing will work for you

```
<div style="position: fixed; margin: 0px; background-color: black; height: 100px; width: 100%;">
  <input type="text" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; margin: 30px 5% 15px 5%;width:90%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE 7 or less, you can probably use the Box-sizing property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp